# Dropdown values selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dropdown in html with values a, b, c,d

I want to submit a form on selection of values.

I know i can use

> .change()

method.

But it will not work if I select same value every time.

I have tried

> .click()

but it is not working in Chrome

Comment: Add a value at the top of the select list with a 0 value (something like "please select below"). Use the .change() function and do nothing if they re-select the default option.

Comment: but my requirement is like that only. that i have to do submit form on selection of same values also

Comment: Your requirement seems flawed. Why would you need to resubmit with the same selection? Trying to figure out why to see if there would be a better solution. I am thinking there is not one. Seems like you should have a "pick an option" option on top to force the onchange.

Comment: Alternatively, you can reset the select after your form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirements are you need to be able to get the same selected value, you can try this. It's ugly, but it will get the job done.

```
$("select").mousedown(function() {

});
```

Keep in mind, this will fire EVERYTIME you click on the list. I strongly suggest revising the requirements to including a blank option at the top of the list as a default.